# Dual boot Windows XP 32 bit and Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows, multi-boot

My system config is AMD phenom-II x2 550 processor, 2x2gb(800fsb)ddr2 zion ram, gigabyte ga-m61pme-s2 motherboard, 160gb sata hdd.

Now I am planning to install Windows XP sp3 (32-bit) and Windows 7 (64bit). My first questions are:

1. Is my system enough for the above mentioned two OSes?
2. Which OS one should be installed first on local disk c: drive?
3. I have both XP and vista drivers on separate disks as provided with my motherboard but don't have drivers for win-7, so can I use my vista driver for win-7?

Comment: I believe this is a 32 bit chip, some one correct me if I am wrong, if I am right you can not run a 64 bit Operating system on it.

Comment: No, it has 64bit support....see details on this page...http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103680

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to Install XP first, then W7, this is the painless way to have a dual bootloader menu after the bios post screen.

Most Vista Drivers will work in W7, but on older hardware W7 will have most of them during install, then do a Windows update, some of the drivers may show up in there as optional updates, install those, they will be the latest versions. Then check Device manager to see if any are missing.

Comment: You actually NEED to install XP first, as it does not seem to give you any option to dual boot (from the last time I installed it anyway)

Comment: Actually no you do not have to install XP first, its just easier, there is a way to repair the bootloader using EasyBCD inside XP....http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1

Comment: That is true, but its a bit inconvenient. Its preferable to do it first.